# Apache Ignite Eviction broken in 2.x, but works fine in 1.9

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I tried Ignite 2.0 and also 2.3 to verify a simple cache eviction. But observed it's broken, but if I revert back to 1.9, it works fine.

Here's my code in 2.x

```
    CacheConfiguration cc = new CacheConfiguration();

    cc.setName("mycache");
    cc.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cc.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
    cc.setEvictionPolicy(new LruEvictionPolicy(5));

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cc);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

    IgniteCache<String,String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cc);

    for(int  i=0;i<10;i++){
        cache.put("k"+i,"val-"+i);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    for(int  i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(cache.get("k"+i));
    }

    System.out.println("============================== " + cache.metrics().getSize());
```

The output prints all 10 cache entries, but it should have only printed from cache keys key5 to k10 with values. Because my LRU max size=5. But if I change the ignite verison to 1.9, things working as expected.

Is this a known issue ? Or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2.0 Ignite uses off-heap memory. It allocates memory by pages, and they may be evicted, when available space comes to an end. You can find description of this mechanism here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions#section-off-heap-memory

So, you can tell Ignite to start evicting pages from some particular data region, when, say, 90% of memory is occupied.

You enabled a different kind of eviction policy, i.e. eviction from Java heap. It doesn't affect data, that is stored in the off-heap space. Heap space is not an alternative, it is just an additional layer of data on top of off-heap memory. Here is documentation on Java heap eviction policy: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions#section-java-heap-cache

Comment: Does this mean, ignite 2.x, it always use off heap(can’t we disable it) and isOnHeapEnabled is just replicating off heap cache on to java heap space ?

Comment: based on your answer, off heap space won’t affect by on heap eviction policies. It make sense. But I observed, in same example, make max entries like 10000 and start putting 10KB entries. And Ignite complains OutOfMemory error after reaching its max entries.  If it really evicts from heap, regardless of entries in offheap, it should not go OOM right ?

Comment: What kind of OOM do you observe? In case of `java.lang.OutOfMemory` please check `Xmx` parameter of JVM and set `LruEvictionPolicy.setMaxMemorySize()` accordingly. In case of `IgniteOutOfMemoryException`, you need to increase `maxSize` property of the corresponding data region (it looks like that your cache uses default data region) Please see details here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration#section-data-regions

Comment: Seems store on heap not an option anymore, but 2.x onwards it can also store on heap. No matter what, Ignite will store cache entries in offheap. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: In offheap, can I disable write to disk(at eviction). I just want off heap cache to evict from itself, without any further tiered storage.

Comment: @Subash, eviction works just like that. When native persistence is disabled, then pages will be dropped without writing to disk. And if you enable persistence, then configured off-heap eviction won't take any effect.